# Let f be a Lebesgue integrable function on (0,1). Show that $g(x)=\int_{x}^{1} (\frac{f(t)}{t})dt $ is Lebesgue measurable.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The actual question asks to show that g is a Lebesgue integrable function on (0,1), but am I correct in assuming that I have to show that g is, first of all, a measurable function?
Or is it trivial in a way i'm not seeing?

I'm trying to show that the preimage of (a,+inf) through g is lebesgue-measurable for every real a, but i'm just going nowhere with it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In fact it's easy to show that $g$ is _continuous_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am struggling with that, could you give me a hand?

Comment: For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\int_E|f|<\epsilon$ if $\mu(E)<\delta$. (Approximate $f$ in $L^1$ by a continuous function...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful in writing the domain of the integral and in explaining all the variables.

If the question is to show a function is integrable over a domain, yes, you should always check it is measurable. Usually, this follows from the fact the function is continuous, but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The function $$h(t,x)=\frac{f(t)}{t}\boldsymbol 1_{\{(x,1)\}},$$

is Lebesgue meausrable on $(0,1)\times (0,1)$. So, if $h$ is integrable on $(0,1)\times (0,1)$, then, by Fubini theorem, $g$ will be Lebesgue measurable. Therefore, in this context, you don't have to worry about the measurability of $g$ and really see about integrability.